# problems with my void function

Tags: c++

The program doesn't run no matter how many times I try and either if I do it over I get new errors.can some help me with this? The void function  is correct. I think there is something wrong with the function being called I'm not sure I just started c++ four days ago.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void calcStats(int , double );

int main()
{
    int num[3];
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        cout << "enter a number "<<endl;
        cin >> num[i] ;
    }
    cout <<"your Number are "<< num[0]<< " , " <<num[1]<< " , "<< num[2]<< endl;

    calcStats(num[2] &maximum ,&minimum, &avg);
    cout <<"hightes number is" << maximum<<endl;
    cout<< "lowest number is" << minimum<< endl;
    cout<< "avg is" << avg<< endl;

    return 0;
}


void calcStats(int num[2], int &maximum, int &minimum, double &avg)
{
    maximum = num[0];
    minimum = num[0];

    // find maximum
    if (num[1]>maximum)
        maximum = num[1];
    if (num[2]>maximum)
        maximum = num[2];

    // find minimum
    if (num[1]<maximum)
      maximum = num[1];
    if (num[2]<maximum)
      maximum = num[2];

    // find average
    avg = static_cast<double>(num[0] + num[1] + num[2])/3.0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show us what kind of debugging you've done.  I expect you to have run your [mcve] within Valgrind or a similar checker, and to have investigated with a debugger such as GDB, for example.  Ensure you've enabled a full set of compiler warnings, too.  What did the tools tell you, and what information are they missing?  And read Eric Lippert's [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 3):

#### Some things to do consider

- Format your code. Use this as a guide. 
  https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html
- Have a different function for each task 
  Instead of having one big function, `calcStats()`, divide it up into multiple small functions such as `getMax(), getMin(), getAverage()`.
  Do not use vague names for the function. It needs to be clear what the function does without looking at the definition of it. For example, I do not know what `calcStats()` does clearly unless I look at the code. On the other hand I know what `getMax()` does, it returns the maximum.

### What is the actual problem?

The problem is that declaration: 
 `void calcStats(int, double)` -- 2 parameters 
does not match the definition: 
 `void calcStats(int [2], int &maximum, int &minimum, int &avg)` -- 4 parameters 
In the declaration you are promising to pass 2 parameters, an integer and a double. But when it comes to the actual definition, your are saying this function takes an array of integers size 2, a references to the variables maximum, minimum and avg.

Error #1: Definition and Declaration should match 
Declaration: `void calcStats(int [], int &, int &, double &)` 
Definition: `void calcStats(int [3], int &min, int &max, double &average){}`

Error #2: Make sure you pass the right arguments 
If the function is expecting array of 3 integers, make sure you give array of 3 integers. Nothing more, nothing less. Remember int[3] means array of 3 integers first one being at index 0. Look up arrays if confused.

## Most importantly

### Format your code. No one can help you if they can't read it.

Comment: the void function is not to be changed though... i do know that i can use smaller functions but the void calcStats was given by my teacher and i'm to complete the function...

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of errors in your code as Azimjon pointed out, here is a working sample:

http://rextester.com/QKG16761